# How to give a resolve value a json object and have it autosuggest when using the promise function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, parameters

I am trying to find a way so that my promise function can autosuggest the resolved value if it is a json object, kind of like in the **axios** NPM dependency.

here is how **axios** does it

```
axios.get("url.com")
.then((res) => {

Here axios will clearly autosuggest and show the 'data' key like such ---> res.data

})
```

Here is the promise function I made

```
const test = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve , reject) => {
     resolve({ object: "Hello There" })
  })
}
```

and here I want the `res` parameter in my `test` function to auto-suggest the `object` located in the resolve

```
test()
.then((res) => {

  Here I want 'object to autosuggest' ---> res.object 

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is probably not be able to figure out the "return" type of the promise since `resolve` can be called whenever with whatever. Adding the generic parameter to `Promise` acts as a type hint though, for example:

```
const test = () => {
  return new Promise<{"object": string;}>((resolve , reject) => {
     resolve({ object: "Hello There" })
  })
}
```

Not sure what development environment you use, so "auto-suggest" is not really clear to me, but I hope using the hint results in what you need.

Edit: I only saw that `typescript` tag, so I assumed the codebase is TypeScript. I guess if Axios provides types and you're using an IDE that uses that information, it might even work without the codebase itself using TypeScript. That would mean adding the type hint wouldn't work. Depending on the IDE, there might be possibilities though.